# Finding analytic function $f$ such that the real part is $u(x,y)=2e^{-x}\sin y +x^2-y^2$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

> I need to find analytic function $f$ such that the real part is $u(x,y)=2e^{-x}\sin y +x^2-y^2$

**My try:**

$$u_x=2x-2\sin y e ^{-x}$$

$$u_y=2 e^{-x}\cos y-2y$$

But when I'm checking Laplace condition:

$$u_{xx}=2+\sin y e^{-x}$$

$$u_{yy}=2e^{-x}\cos y-2y$$

and $u_{xx}+u_{yy}\neq 0$

Should I check Laplace condition at all?

Comment: A factor $2$ is missing in  $u_{xx}$, and your $u_{yy}$ is identical to $u_y$, i.e. you did not compute the derivative at all ...

Comment: You must have $u_{xx}+u_{yy}=0$, of course. Check your computations of $u_{xx}$ and $u_{yy}$ (both are not correct). Anyway, I don't think you have to be concerned with that. Regarding your question, start by finding $u_x$ and then use the Cauchy-Riemann equation to find $v$ (hint: you will have to integrate $u_x$).

Comment: Ok thanks, I realy don't know how I missed that

Comment: See this post: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/415574/find-an-analytic-function-with-real-part-fracyx2y2

Comment: You probably can find $f$ with a bit try-and-error. For example, $x^2 - y^2$ is the real part of $z^2$.

Comment: @MartinR Great, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$u_{xx}=2+2\sin y\space e^{-x}$$
$$u_{yy}=-2e^{-x}\sin y-2$$
$$\text{So }u_{xx}+u_{yy}=0$$